# Why can 2 spark structured streaming instances read the same messages from Azure EventHub even if they are using the same consumer group

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

What I understand from the official document is that, when using a same consumer group, 2 consumers can not read the same message. If I still want to process a same message, I must use a different consumer group.

I try to test if this is true with 2 simple Spark structured streaming app. It just reads all the messages from the hub and write them to a table in memory. Here is my code for the 2 apps:

```
ehConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString' : connectionString,
  'eventhubs.consumerGroup': "group1"
}

df = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()
df.writeStream.format("memory").queryName("sink").outputMode("append").start()
```

Then I tried to send some messages to the hub, using this

```
dfnum = spark.range(1, 8)
dfnum = dfnum.select(col('id').cast('string')).withColumnRenamed('id', 'body')
# dfnum.show()

ehWriteConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString' : connectionString
}

ds = dfnum.select("body").write.format("eventhubs").options(**ehWriteConf).option("checkpointLocation", "tmp/checkpoint").save()
```

The problem is that all the Spark Structured Streaming apps can still read all the message from the Eventhub, which is not like what the official document says.

Here is the result from spark application 1:

```
+----+------+---------+--------------------+---------+------------+
|body|offset|partition|        enqueuedTime|publisher|partitionKey|
+----+------+---------+--------------------+---------+------------+
|   4|  1248|        0|2020-05-31 14:00:...|     null|        null|
|   1|  1296|        0|2020-05-31 14:00:...|     null|        null|
|   3|  1152|        1|2020-05-31 14:00:...|     null|        null|
|   2|  1200|        1|2020-05-31 14:00:...|     null|        null|
|   5|  1344|        0|2020-05-31 14:01:...|     null|        null|
|   6|  1248|        1|2020-05-31 14:01:...|     null|        null|
|   7|  1296|        1|2020-05-31 14:01:...|     null|        null|
+----+------+---------+--------------------+---------+------------+
```

And here is the result from the spark application 2:

```
+----+------+---------+--------------------+---------+------------+
|body|offset|partition|        enqueuedTime|publisher|partitionKey|
+----+------+---------+--------------------+---------+------------+
|   4|  1248|        0|2020-05-31 14:00:...|     null|        null|
|   3|  1152|        1|2020-05-31 14:00:...|     null|        null|
|   1|  1296|        0|2020-05-31 14:00:...|     null|        null|
|   2|  1200|        1|2020-05-31 14:00:...|     null|        null|
|   5|  1344|        0|2020-05-31 14:01:...|     null|        null|
|   6|  1248|        1|2020-05-31 14:01:...|     null|        null|
|   7|  1296|        1|2020-05-31 14:01:...|     null|        null|
+----+------+---------+--------------------+---------+------------+
```

The order is a bit different, but the content is all the same.

Do I misunderstand something here?

Comment: Can you try setting useExclusiveReceiver? I think this is set to false by default.

Comment: I tried the setting but it seems that things stay the same.
In the document, they also state that each partition can have 5 active readers per partition per consumer group. Does that mean if I have equal or lower than 5 Spark Structured Streaming apps, then I can stream from EventHub without the need of consumer group?